# No iOS device found, is it plugged in? in ideviceinstaller/ideviceinfo

Tags: ios, iphone, linux, ipad, usb

I am getting the following error when I run `ideviceinstaller`/`ideviceinfo` commands:

```
No iOS device found, is it plugged in?
```

My iPhone is certainly plugged is and visible in `lsusb`.

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain how this question is off-topic? What else would you use `ideviceinstaller` for if not for development?

Answer (score 10):

Restart the `usbmuxd` service and your device will show up normally:

```
systemctl restart usbmuxd.service
```

Your iPhone will vibrate if it connected successfully.

Comment: down vote I think that command is for stsremd not OSX. Either way it's not on my Mojave

Comment: It's not working on MacOS, at least not for 14.x/15.x

Comment: What makes you think this question is only valid for MacOS? The OP did not state any OS. I have the same problem on Ubuntu. Worked before; suddenly stopped working. "systemctl restart usbmuxd.service" solved the problem for me.

Comment: This worked for me (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS)

Answer (score 0):

there is a file 'lockdownd' and it might have 0700 permissions with the owner as root. You should try `chmod 0705 lockdownd`. restart was not necessary for me. You might also run `ideviceinstaller/ideviceinfo` as root or with sudo. You might not have a recent version or you might have multiple versions installed. There is an xcode version-ish and there is a `brew`.

UPDATE there are a lot of details missing here, however, I gt this error when I had installed libimodiledevices with `brew` and allowed or told brew to clean the other dynlinks. That disabled ideviceinfo etc because of a missing dynlib. For example flutter prepackages these tools and brew breaks it.